# Is it possible to call waitpid multiple time ? [UNIX] [C]

Tags: c, unix, process

My teacher assigned a work which consists of making a pseudo-scheduler. I'm now stuck at the most important part. The line that is giving me trouble is the *waitpid* line at the end. Basically I want the parent process to wait for all his child that is why I've done that. But the code freezes at that point. When I comment it, it runs to the end but nothing is written to STDOUT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define LOOP_SIZE 20;

/* SIG HANDLERS DEFINITION */
void parentsighandler(int);

/* GLOBAL VARIABLE DEFINITION */ 
pid_t n, ppid;
int nb_args, compteur;

// array of pid_t to send signals to child
pid_t  *child_pids;     


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    if (argc - 1 >= 1 ){
        // Variable initialisation
        compteur = 0;
        nb_args = argc - 1;
        child_pids = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(pid_t)); 

        // String for sprintf
        char sstr[40]; 
        char rstr[40];


        // Initializing all the pipes for the processes
        int p[2 * (argc - 1)];  

        // getting the pid of the parent process
        ppid = getpid();

        //Initializing all pipes
        int i, j, status, stop_val;
        for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++){
            if (pipe(&p[2*i]) == -1){
                perror("pipe failed");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i ++){
            switch( n = fork()){
                case -1:
                    perror("fork failed");
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                case 0:
                    /* CHILD */
                    if (0 == (stop_val = atoi(argv[i+1]))){
                        perror("atoi failed");
                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    close(p[i*2]);
                    for (j = 0; j < 20 ; j++){
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "here\n", 5);
                        if (j % stop_val == 0){
                            kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);    
                        } 
                        sprintf(sstr, "Je suis le proc %d : message %d\n", getpid(), i);
                        write(p[i * 2 + 1], sstr, 40);
                    }   
                    close(p[i*2+1]);
                    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                default:
                    /* PARENT - process scheduling */
                    child_pids[i] = n;
                    kill(n, SIGSTOP);
            } 
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Debut de l'ordonnancement\n",26);

        // Setting up the signal
        signal(SIGUSR1, parentsighandler); 

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "before wait\n",12);   
        // The parent as to wait for all child to finish
        for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i ++){
        //  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "beit\n",12);  
            printf("value of pid n%d is %d\n", i, child_pids[i]);
    //      waitpid(child_pids[i], &status, 0);
        //  close(p[i * 2 + 1]); // closing the write end of the pipe
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "cefore main\n",12);
        char mystr[15];
        sprintf(mystr, "compteur : %d\n", compteur);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, mystr, 15);
        while(1){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "refore main\n",12);
            kill(child_pids[compteur], SIGCONT);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "jefore main\n",12);
            while(read(p[2 * compteur], rstr, 40) > 0){
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, rstr, 40);
            }       
        }
    } else {
        perror("Not enough args\n");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    return 0;
}

void parentsighandler(int sig){
    if (sig == SIGUSR1){
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "passe dans sig handler\n", 23);
        kill(child_pids[compteur], SIGSTOP);
        if (compteur == nb_args){
            compteur = 0;   
        } else {
            compteur ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read documentation of [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) ? It does not forbid calling `waitpid` several times (even if that might not do what you dream)

Comment: BTW, read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn to use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)...

Comment: OT: regarding: `child_pids = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(pid_t));`  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did read the doc of waitpid. But oddly my program stops at this exact moment and I don't know for what reason. And I don't know if it is the right way to wait for alll children. Is there a more efficient way of doing it. **Thank you** for the advice for the _strace_ command

Comment: @user3629249 OOPSIE. You"re right, I forgot to check for null. Adding it rigth now !

Comment: OT: regarding: `perror("Not enough args\n");`  at this point, there is no system error, so the text message will be 'success',  It is typical at this point to output a USAGE message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s number [[number]]\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `switch( n = fork()){
                case -1:
                    perror("fork failed");
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`  At this point it is not a good idea to exit the program.  Rather, any open pipes should be closed and any child processes should be exited/killed before calling `_exit()`

Comment: regarding: `if (0 == (stop_val = atoi(argv[i+1]))){`  The function: `atoi()` does not actually return an error condition and the user may have placed  0 somewhere in the command line arguments.  Suggest calling: `strtol()` as that does have an error status that can be checked

Comment: regarding: `for (j = 0; j < 20 ; j++){
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "here\n", 5);
                        if (stop_val % j == 0){
                            kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);    
                        } ` this assumes that all command line argumentd are less than 20.  This is not a valid assumption as nothing in the code is enforcing that assumption

Comment: @user3629249 Is there a way of exiting all processes in one shot. Does exiting the parent process terminate all child processes ?

Comment: to exit all the child processes. suggest: `while( wait( NULL ) != -1 ){;}`

Comment: @user3629249 You'e pointed a great mistake the stop_val should be the other way around  : j % stop_val. I'll change to strtol() for the error catching possibility.

Comment: suggest the parent signal handler be setup before starting all the child processes.

Comment: It seems each child process is run for a small amount of time, then killed, that the next child process is started, etc.  Probably not what you want to do

Comment: the parent signal handler is not setup until after all the children are started, however, it is being called by `kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);` in the child process before the child exits.  This will very likely kill the parent, immediately

Comment: regarding: `default:
                    /* PARENT - process scheduling */
                    child_pids[i] = n;
                    kill(n, SIGSTOP);`  This will very likely kill the child before it has done anything.   Suggest rethinking the details of how the child processes are killed and when they are killed

Comment: @user3629249 What I want to do is to pause all child processes and then listen to them one by one for a certain amount of message

Comment: @AlexandreManeta: avoid commenting your own question but instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53997676/edit) it to improve it

Comment: Suggest a semaphore for each child process.  the child would then run up to the `sem_wait()` and sit there until the `main()` performs a `sem_post()` for that semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

why is the parent (seeming) to stop at the instruction:

```
waitpid(child_pids[i], &status, 0);
```

because the child is killing the parent, before the parent has setup a signal handler